# Do native French speakers view "th" as a digraph?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe

French, like English has a few digraphs, e.g. "ph" /f/ in both French and English, and "ch", /ʃ/ in French, /tʃ/ in English.

In words such as:

> thermomètre
>
> mathématique

is "th" considered a digraph with the pronunciation /t/; or two separate letters, "t" and "h" with the respective pronunciations /t/ and // (silent)? Obviously, both interpretations give the same pronunciation, but I'm wondering which one, if either, is considered "proper".

Answer (score 4):

Referring to [the list of French digraphs on Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_digrammes_et_trigrammes#Fran%C3%A7ais), `th` is not present in the list, suggesting the French language does not seem to consider it as a digraph.

However, there is an [existing page for the `th` digraph on French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th_(digramme)#Autres_langues), listing its use in different languages, and stating:

> This digraph is also sometimes used in other languages, such as French (in this case, the digraph comes from Ancient Greek), to represent the `/t/` sound.

---

In fact, most of the French words featuring `th` seem to come from Ancient Greek:

- [ἄνθρωπος (án**th**ropos)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%84%CE%BD%CE%B8%CF%81%CF%89%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%82): an**th**ropologie
- [ἐνθουσιασμός (en**th**ousiasmós)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%90%CE%BD%CE%B8%CE%BF%CF%85%CF%83%CE%B9%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%BC%CF%8C%CF%82): en**th**ousiasme
- [μάθημα (má**th**ēma)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CE%AC%CE%B8%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%B1): ma**th**ématique
- [παθολογία (pá**th**os)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%B8%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%AF%CE%B1): pa**th**ologie
- [θερμός (**th**ermós)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B8%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%BC%CF%8C%CF%82): **th**ermomètre
- etc...

Comment: I agree that they're not considered digrams, but I don't think the fact that they come from ancient Greek is an argument for it. Basically any /f/ sound in Greek words (which is one letter in Greek, just like *th*) gives a "*ph*" in French, which is digram.